# Calculate total hours worked in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to calculate the exact work time of a worker, so the data has been stored in mysql database table like

```
Date              work-id     Start-Time      Close-Time 
2018-07-14         201        6:50 PM         7:00 PM   
2018-07-14         301        6:50 PM         7:00 PM 
2018-07-14         401        6:50 PM         7:25 PM 
2018-07-14         501        6:55 PM         7:15 PM 
2018-07-14         601        8:00 PM         8:45 PM
```

I need the output like 10+25+45= 80 Minutes.

so the avg work time is 75 Mins. But this output is wrong. I need the output like 10+25+45= 80 Minutes (Output required). The work-id 201,301 both are completed at same time(10 minutes) and work-id 401,501 both has been completed within 25 minutes so the worker work time is (10+25)=35 minutes.
now the worker completed another work(work-id 601) with 45 minutes.
So the worker total work time will be (10+25+45) 80 minutes.
How it will be calculated in php with Nth number of data?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. And it seems to me that the non-MySQL tags are irrelevant in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have those 4 things, you can calculate time worked by using code looking like this:

```
<?php
$worktimes = [
    ['2018-07-14','201','6.50 PM','7.00 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','301','6.50 PM','7.00 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','401','6.50 PM','7.25 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','501','6.55 PM','7.15 PM']
];


foreach($worktimes as $worktime){

    $workerId = $worktime[1];

    $start = strtotime($worktime[0].' '.$worktime[2]);
    $end = strtotime($worktime[0].' '.$worktime[3]);

    $timeworkedInSeconds = $end-$start;

    $timeworkedInMinutes = $timeworkedInSeconds/60;

    $timeworkedByWorker[$workerId][]=$timeworkedInMinutes;
}

foreach($timeworkedByWorker as $workerId => $times){
    echo join('+',$times).' = '.array_sum($times).PHP_EOL;
}
```

However, gouping them and calculating average, is another story. But if you provide enough data (with multiple rows of same worker and multiple workers)  can help out more.

UPDATED:
after you updated the data in main question, and it became more clear where the data come from I think this is what you really needed.

```
<?php
$worktimes = [
    ['2018-07-14', '201', '6:50 PM', '7:00 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14', '301', '6:50 PM', '7:00 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14', '401', '6:50 PM', '7:25 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14', '501', '6:55 PM', '7:15 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14', '601', '8:00 PM', '8:45 PM'],
];


foreach($worktimes as $worktime){

    $start = strtotime($worktime[0].' '.$worktime[2]);
    $end = strtotime($worktime[0].' '.$worktime[3]);

    $timeInSeconds = $end-$start;
    $timeInMinutes = $timeInSeconds/60;

    $workTimesInMinutes[]=$timeInMinutes;
}

$workTimesInMinutes = array_unique($workTimesInMinutes);
echo join('+',$workTimesInMinutes).' = '.array_sum($workTimesInMinutes).PHP_EOL;
```

Please have in mind, however, that you have NO GUARANTEE two different jobs took the same amount of minutes, so without some workerID grouping you cannot be sure that the amount of time is really correct. I.e reading data job takes 10 mintues, and saving data job takes 10 minutes, but one of them is ignored, because taking "already known" number of minutes. I think grouping by time taken is unsafe.

Comment: I don't want all the time. I want the exact working time of this date which is 35 minutes.

Comment: this is not a 4 data it is a dynamic generated data, it can be more than that, Like:
 $worktimes = [
    ['2018-07-14','201','6:50 PM','7:00 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','301','6:50 PM','7:00 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','401','6:50 PM','7:25 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','501','6:55 PM','7:15 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','501','8:00 PM','8:45 PM']
];

Comment: I meant 4 columns of the data. The code I gave you doesn't care how many records are there.
Your data is not sufficient to write you the code you want because the numbers you mention in your question do not match the data from the array.

Comment: @AchintaKundu I updated the code so it shows the pieces and sums in minutes per worker, hopefully that gets you where you need.

Comment: This is the Array
$worktimes = [
    ['2018-07-14','201','6.50 PM','7.00 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','301','6.50 PM','7.00 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','401','6.50 PM','7.25 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','501','6.55 PM','7.15 PM'],
    ['2018-07-14','601','8.00 PM','8.45 PM']
];

Output required 80 minutes
(10+25+45)
i don't need all the result. I have already explain it please read my query.

Comment: see my updated answer, but the answer with your data gives:
10+35+20+45 = 110
because that's what the provided rows contain